# i can consume the api through rails server but Rspec failing it please provide me the solution

Tags: ruby-on-rails

actually i can consume the below api but when i want to test through rspec it failing all the test in the command line interface if you want some more information related to the problem please let me know i will provide

## class Recipe < ActiveRecord::Base

```
class Recipe
   include HTTParty

   hostport = ENV['FOOD2FORK_SERVER_AND_PORT'] || 'www.food2fork.com'
   user_key = ENV['FOOD2FORK_KEY']

   base_uri "http://#{hostport}/api"
   default_params key: user_key
   format :json

   def self.for term
      get("/search", query: {q: term})["recipes"]
   end
end

this is my gem file 

source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '4.2.3'
gem 'sqlite3', group: :development
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc
gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby
gem 'capybara', '~> 2.4.4'
gem 'poltergeist', '~> 1.6.0'
gem 'phantomjs', '~> 1.9.8.0'
gem 'execjs'

group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'

  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  gem 'spring'
end

gem 'httparty'

# Windows does not include zoneinfo files, so bundle the tzinfo-data gem
gem 'tzinfo-data', platforms: [:mingw, :mswin, :x64_mingw, :jruby]

group :production do
  gem 'pg'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Comment: show the failing rspec tests

Answer (score 0):

Rspec does not support external http  request. Instead you can use webmock for testing.